# Grunt variable as filename and file path

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to use Grunt option to define a file path and file name. This used to work but now I'm getting an unexpected token error.

```js
var myTarget = grunt.option('target');
'build/assets/css/' + myTarget + '.css': 'source/scss/' + myTarget + '/styles.scss'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the special placeholders for variables in file names and strings. First, you should load the option (using `grunt.option()`) or configuration (using `grunt.congif()`), as an option for the Grunt `initConfig` method. Then you should use the special placeholders `<%= varname %>` to use the loaded options or configurations.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    target : grunt.option('target'),
    ...
        files : {
            'build/assets/css/<%= target %>.css' : 'source/scss/<%= target %>/styles.scss'
        }
    ...
});
```

Configuration can also load an object, so the special placeholder can match object properties too:

```
grunt.config('definitions', (function() {
    return {
        target : 'my-target'
    };
})());
```

Later on your config:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    config : grunt.config('definitions'),
    ...
        files : {
            'build/assets/css/<%= config.target %>.css' : 'source/scss/<%= config.target %>/styles.scss'
        }
    ...
});
```

Read more about Grunt [option](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option), [config](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config) and [templates](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template) in the Grunt official website.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @RobC as per the sintax, it seems like using in as an object `key : value` notation (note the `:`) so the concatenation won't be possible in that case. Is better to use the template notation. And, it's easy to assume is used for compiling sass in a basic file pattern as `{ destination : source }` notation.